# Not getting results from SpeechRecognizer class?

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I have a maind UI class that has button which instantiate a class that is implementing SpeechRecognizer  library to convert speech from text.

```
btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startNoiseProcessService();
            }
        });
```

startNoiseProcessService() is a function which is calling another class object.

```
public void startNoiseProcessService() {

                StreamService ss = new StreamService(this);
                String s = ss.startStreaming();
                if ( s.equals("NA") ) {
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),threadCnt + 
                            "Opps! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
            }

}
```

**StreamService** class implements **SpeechRecognizer API**.

This StreamService class is getting called perfectly fine and problem lies is I am unable to get the converted text from speech at the time after results are calculated by `onResults(Bundle)` method.

I need the converted text to update my textbox and I am not getting it.

startStreaming() implementation:

```
 public String startStreaming() {

            text = "";

            if ( !SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(context) ) {
                text = "NA";
                return text;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "started taking input");
            sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                     RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);


            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);

            sr.setRecognitionListener( new mylistener());
            sr.startListening(intent);

     }
```

Comment: When you debug your code, `onResults` never gets called? Are you testing this on a physical device? Did you try putting break points on the other methods of the listener to see if maybe another one is getting called instead?

Comment: onResults Method is getting called but this method is in another class  which is getting called from UI Class. I need the results from this method at the time when this method is called to display the results in UI class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I think you can't have the results at the time `sr.startListening(intent)` is called. You need to get the results using the `onResults` method of the listener and process the text that comes inside the `Bundle` from there.

The way I implemented this was to have a `Service` in charge of handling the `SpeechRecognizer`. Then when `onResults` is called I send the text back to the original caller using a message handler. You can see details on how to do this here: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html